# htaccess rewrite condition and rewrite rule for redirecting to a page using a particular name

Tags: .htaccess

I have a link linking to http://mysite.com/profile.php?username=myname and when we click it

the browser will show http://mysite.com/myname. I have already wrote other links in htaccess

and I do not want to change them all ...

Can someone help me ?

Comment: Your question is not clear , can you explain ?

Comment: I  have created http://mysite.com/profile.php?username=myname.. And i want at my site users to open page as : http://mysite.com/myname

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(\w+)/?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^  profile.php?username=%1 [L,QSA]
```

- Flag `NC`: [Apache <sup>Docs</sup>: flag_nc](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_nc)
- Flag `L`: [Apache <sup>Docs</sup>: flag_l](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_l)
- Flag `QSA`: [Apache <sup>Docs</sup>: flag_qsa](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa)

Answer (score 0):

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^/]+) /profile.php?username=$1 [NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

In your .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/profile\.php\?username=([A-Za-z0-9]+) /$1
```

Source:
http://www.phpriot.com/articles/search-engine-urls/2